# Pine script I can't use array get in ta cross

Tags: tradingview-api

I am trying to set up an alarm system for swing order blocks, but I cannot use array.get in ta.cross. I think it's because they are variable, but I don't know if there is a method. I would be glad if you help me

Code Block:

```
var ob_top = array.new_float(0)
var ob_btm = array.new_float(0)
var ob_left = array.new_int(0)
var ob_type = array.new_int(0)

//Delete internal order blocks box coordinates if top/bottom is broken
for element in ob_type
    index = array.indexof(ob_type, element)

    if close < array.get(ob_btm, index) and element == 1
        array.remove(ob_top, index) 
        array.remove(ob_btm, index) 
        array.remove(ob_left, index) 
        array.remove(ob_type, index)
        bull_ob_break := true

    else if close > array.get(ob_top, index) and element == -1
        array.remove(ob_top, index) 
        array.remove(ob_btm, index)
        array.remove(ob_left, index) 
        array.remove(ob_type, index)
        bear_ob_break := true
```

What I want to do is exactly something like this:

```
    if ta.cross(high,array.get(ob_btm, index)) and element == 1
        bull_ob_alert := true
```

If you want to see the full code, just tell me to add it. Thank you!

pine script, trade, array.get, ta.cross